# Indentation in empty lines

Tags: brackets, indent

I'm using the [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) text editor.  Is there a way to preserve indentation in empty lines?

Before Indention

[image: before indenting]

After Indention lines 4 and 6 should have an indent guide too

[image: after indenting, lines 4 and 6 should have an indent guide too]

If I indent again (and again, and again...), lines 4 and 6 remain empty without an indent guide. How to fix that?

By the way, I'm using [Indent Guides for Brackets](https://github.com/lkcampbell/brackets-indent-guides)

Comment: Which editor are you using? Some support this, others don't easily.

Comment: Brackets and the extension: Intent Guides for Brackets :D

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize it was a proper name!